# HTML/JS storing input number in variable and using that variable in JS for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create n list items where n is user-specified input (a number). However, for some reason the JS file cannot read the variable and use it in the for loop. If I pass a constant integer to the JS file from html file, the for loop works. If i simply access the variable in another functino and alert it, it works. But accessing the variable in the function with for loop never works.
*NEW* What I want to achieve is to make a user specify a number of people, e.g. 3 (on one html page), then on another html page I want to open up n (in this case 3) text fields where the users can specify their names on, e.g. John, Kim, Ronnie.

HTML

```
<div id="startBox" class="startBox" >
    <h3>How many people are involved in this project?</h3>
    <br>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type= "number" id = "userNum">
    </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id = "submitNum" onclick="saveUserNum();window.location.href='usernames.html'">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function insertNames(){
var userNum = document.getElementById("userNum").value;
for( var i = 0; i < userNum; i++){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var li_text = document.createTextNode("Abekat");
    li.appendChild(li_text);
    document.getElementById("name_ul").appendChild(li);
}
```

}

*EDIT*

The list items should appear on another html file page that looks as follows:

```
 <div id="name_ul" class="startBox">
    <h3>Please enter the name of each member</h3>
        <script>insertNames()</script>  
</div>
```

saveUserNum() is:

```
function saveUserNum(){
var userNum = document.getElementById("userNum").value;
alert(userNum);
```

}
but I dont think it's necessary.

Comment: can you show html structure ? Where the  `saveUserNum()` func ? Show us

Comment: Yes sorry, I have added all infomration now

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Could you be a little more descriptive

Comment: I updated the text to include what I want to achieve

Comment: if this code is on another page it will never work.  `<div id="name_ul" class="startBox">
    <h3>Please enter the name of each member</h3>
    <script>insertNames()</script>
  </div>`

Comment: I showed him a way to solve his problem and updated my answer. Please read carefully and adjust. It will work without error. Good Luck!

Comment: Why not use forms as [they are meant to be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms). Add an `action` attribute to your `form` element pointing to the second HTML page. Remove the `onclick` from the submit button. Then get the value of `userNum` from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try parseInt(); ike below

```
function insertNames(){
    var userNum = document.getElementById("userNum").value;
    userNum = parseInt(userNum);
    for( var i = 0; i < userNum; i++){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var li_text = document.createTextNode("Abekat");
        li.appendChild(li_text);
        document.getElementById("name_ul").appendChild(li);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where do you calling insertNames ?

Comment: I updated the post now to include everything, sorry

Comment: If you call insertNames from another html. The document refers to current html, which does not have #userNum. So, it should be in the same file

Answer (score 0):

***FİRST PAGE***

Let this be your "index.html" page. Here you can save the userNum item to local storage. I mentioned it in the comment lines.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>STACKOVERFLOW</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="startBox" class="startBox">
    <h3>How many people are involved in this project?</h3>
    <br>
    <form id="form1">
      <input type="number" id="userNum">
    </form>
    <br>
    <br> 
    <input type="submit" id="submitNum" onclick="saveUserNum(); window.location.href='index2.html'"> <!--Name the page where you want it to appear. I said "index2" to for example; Don't forget!! -->
  </div>

  <script>
    function saveUserNum() {
      var userNum = document.getElementById("userNum").value;
      // Save local storage to UserNUM !!!!!!
      localStorage.setItem("userNum", JSON.stringify(userNum));
      alert(`your select ${userNum} User`);
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

***SECOND PAGE***

This is where you want to send item 2.make it your page. Let's call it "index2.html"; the codes on this page will take the userNum item we have saved to localStorage with index html and print it to the screen as we want. I mentioned it in the comment lines.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="name_ul" class="startBox">
    <h3>Please enter the name of each member</h3>

  </div>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", insertNames); //  once the page is loaded, the function will be triggered.

    function insertNames() {
      // gET UserNum from local storage
      let userNum = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userNum"));
      for (var i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var li_text = document.createTextNode("Abekat");
        li.appendChild(li_text);
        document.getElementById("name_ul").appendChild(li);
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I made it clear that what you wanted to do was done. You can change their names and apply them according to your own html structure. If you want to know more about Local storage : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: This does work, but not exactly the way i want it to. I have updated the post now to include everything, sorry!